# Reduce and FullSimplify are being lazy

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

The following is a curiosity I just observed. Consider the following `Reduce` command:

```
Reduce[
  Exp[r + I f] == Exp[R + I F]
   && Exp[r - I f] == Exp[R - I F]
   && r > 0 && R > 0 && 0 < f < 2 \[Pi] && 0 < F < 2 \[Pi]
  , {r, f}] // FullSimplify
```

> `0 < F < 2 \[Pi] && R > 0 && r == R && f == F + I (r - R)`

In the above, even though `r==R` is clearly stated in the result, `f` is still given in terms of

`f == F + I (r - R)`

instead of just `f == F`. And that despite `FullSimplify` having been applied.

In this trivial case this is of course not a huge issue. However, does this mean that we should in general expect `Reduce` with `FullSimplify` to overlook obvious simplifications in more complicated systems as well, so that a seemingly complicated output likely might still be hugely reducible?

By the way, I am on Windows 10 and

```
$VersionNumber
```

> `11.1`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) and the `Backsubstitution` option for [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

constraints = r > 0 && R > 0 && 0 < f < 2 π && 0 < F < 2 π;

Assuming[constraints, 
 Reduce[Exp[r + I f] == Exp[R + I F] && Exp[r - I f] == Exp[R - I F] && 
    constraints, {r, f}, Backsubstitution -> True] // FullSimplify]

(* r == R && f == F *)
```

Or,

```
Reduce[Exp[r + I f] == Exp[R + I F] && Exp[r - I f] == Exp[R - I F] && 
   constraints, {r, f}, Backsubstitution -> True] // 
 FullSimplify[#, constraints] &

(* r == R && f == F *)
```

Comment: +1 Wow that looks handy, cool!